# How to fix corrupted GUI on Ubuntu Xenial Xerus

Tags: 16.04, unity, gui

I've been using Ubuntu for a while, A few days ago, I installed a system update and right after the installation, the Unity started flickering. I've tried several solutions on the web but nothing fixed my problem. I would be grateful if you could help.

Note: Please enable captions while watching the video.

Video Related to the Problem
https://youtu.be/lrcEUtbV5bI

Hardware
Device: Dell Latitude E6410
Processor:  Intel® Core™ i7 CPU M 620 @ 2.67GHz × 4
Graphics:   Intel® Ironlake Mobile

Software
OS:         Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
GUI:        Unity 7.4.0
Kernel: Linux 4.10.0-42-generic
Architecture:   x86-64

Solutions I’ve Tried
https://askubuntu.com/a/761882/779094
https://askubuntu.com/a/825204/779094
https://askubuntu.com/a/761689/779094
https://askubuntu.com/a/804895/779094
I've also tried dpkg and fsck under Linux 4.10.0-42-generic (recovery mode)

Answer (score 0):

you can reinstall desktop 
[How to restore default Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789481/how-to-restore-default-unity)
try it but not sure

or
install gnome desktop

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/05/install-gnome-3-20-ubuntu-16-04-lts

https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-install-gnome-38-on-ubuntu/

[install gnome-shell on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766071/install-gnome-shell-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already tried the first solution you suggested, it didn't work. For the other suggestion, I should say that I prefer fixing The Unity and understanding the reason behind the problem instead of replacing it with another GUI.